# git diff :: overriding .gitconfig external tool

Tags: git, git-diff, meld

I've configured `git` to use `meld` as an external diff tool:

```
$ cat ~/.gitconfig | grep -A2 "\[diff\]"
[diff]
        tool = vimdiff
        external = git-meld
```

... where `git-meld` is:

```
$ cat $(which git-meld)
#!/bin/bash
meld $2 $5
```

However sometimes (e.g. in the case of very minor diffs or if I want to easily copy-paste something from the diff text) I just want to see the differences on the shell and avoid `meld`'s spawning delay.

Is there a way (e.g. a command line argument) to override the `.gitconfig` settings and instruct `git` to just do a simple text-only diff?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

For your general question: pretty much all options can be overridden on the command line using `-c`:

> -c <name>=<value>
>
> Pass a configuration parameter to the command. The value given will override values from configuration files. The <name> is expected in the same format as listed by git config (subkeys separated by dots).

That said, `diff.external` is a problem. You can change its value, but there is no way to unset it on the command line (that I can see). However, `git diff` does have a custom option to ignore the `diff.external` setting: you can use

```
git diff --no-ext-diff
```

Answer (score 8):

Another option is to use `git difftool`, which is just like `git diff` but always uses a GUI tool (and by default prompts you for one).

When you use `git diff`, git uses the tool specified in `diff.external`.

When you use `git difftool`, git uses the tool in specified in `diff.tool`.

What I like to do is leave `diff.external` *unset,* and then use `git difftool` when I want a GUI diff, and just `git diff` when I don't.

You can also turn the prompt off for `git difftool` by sending:

> git config --global difftool.prompt false